# Can pygame recognize simple geometric shapes?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pygame

I want to create a bunch of simple geometric shapes (colored rectangles, triangles, squares ...) using pygame and then later analyze their relations and features. I first tried [turtle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html) but apparently that is only a graphing library and cannot keep track of the shapes it creates and I wonder if the same holds true for Pygame. To illustrate the point, say I have this script:

```
# Import a library of functions called 'pygame'
import pygame
from math import pi

# Initialize the game engine
pygame.init()

# Define the colors we will use in RGB format
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE =  (  0,   0, 255)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
RED =   (255,   0,   0)

# Set the height and width of the screen
size = [800, 600]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Example code for the draw module")

#Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:

    # This limits the while loop to a max of 10 times per second.
    # Leave this out and we will use all CPU we can.
    clock.tick(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done=True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    # Draw a rectangle outline
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [75, 10, 50, 20], 2)
    # Draw a solid rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [150, 10, 50, 20])
    # Draw an ellipse outline, using a rectangle as the outside boundaries
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, RED, [225, 10, 50, 20], 2) 
    # Draw a circle
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, [60, 250], 40)
    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    # This MUST happen after all the other drawing commands.
    pygame.display.flip()

# Be IDLE friendly
pygame.quit()
```

It creates this image:

[image]

Now, suppose I save the image created by Pygame. Is there a way Pygame would be able to detect the shapes, colors and coordinates from the image?

Answer (score 3):

PyGame is a gaming library - it helps with making graphics and audio and controllers for games. It doesn't have support to detect objects in a preexisting image.

What you want is OpenCV (It has Python bindings) - this is made to "understand" things about an image.

One popular math algorithm used to detect shapes (or edges) of any sort are Hough Transforms. You can read more about it here - http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html

OpenCV has Hough transform functions inside it which are very useful.

---

You could attempt to make your own Hough transform code and use it ... but libraries make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It can, but pygame is also good for making games but unfortunately, you can't convert them to IOS or Android, in the past, there was a program called PGS4A which allowed you to convert pygame projects to android but sadly, the program has been discontinued and now, there is no way. On this case, my sggestion would be that if you ever wanted to do this, download Android Studio from this link "http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#top" and google on how to use libgdx with Android Studio, this guy has an extremely helpful tutorial which has a lot of parts, but if your goal is to make commercial applications, I would highly recommend you to check this tutorial "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pwJv1QRSPM" extremely helpful. Good luck with your goals and hoped this helped you on making your decision, but python is a good programming language, it will give you the basic idea on how programming is.